# Google Sheets interpret numbers with one decimal point as date

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

With locale set to Brazil (number format is 24.999,75 and date is 20/5/2017) typing a number with a point separator (.) results in different interpretations depending on the number digits after the point:

#1 after the separator = interpreted as a date
[image]

#2 after the separator = interpreted as text
[image]

#3 after the separator = interpreted as a number without the point.
[image]

Are there any work arounds for this?
I tried lots of locales and all of them present the same or analog behaviour. I fear users will eventually make a mistake inside my sheet typing a point instead of a comma and I'll have to track it down in the future.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What is the purspose of writting a number with a dot when using Brazil as the regional setting?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Data > Data Validation and set the cell to accept only valid dates (using your own textual help for users) refusing and invalid entry.

[image]